# product of vector subspaces of homogenous polynomial of a fixed degree

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, vector-spaces

Denote $P_k$ to be the $K$ vector space of homogeneous polynomials in $K[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ with total degree $k$. Is it easy to find the minimum dimension $d$ such that any vector subspace $U\le P_k$ of dimension $d$ yields 
$U\cdot P_k = P_{2k}$,
where here  $U\cdot P_k$ is the vector space spanned by the product i.e. 
$$U\cdot P_k:= \langle fg : f\in U, g\in P_k \rangle$$

Comment: An easy lower bound can be given. Let me use $P_{k,n}$ to emphasize the number of variables in your notation. Then $d$ must be greater than $\dim P_{k,n-1}$. Also, $U\cdot P_k$ as you define it may not be closed under addition, so it is better to use the more standard notation, that it is the vector space generated by the products.

Comment: Yes, it make sense to say vector space spanned by the products. I've edited it. Thanks